# How can I better understand likelihood functions of generalized linear models?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

In reading about various generalized linear models, I have found that I can understand the structural form of models, but I can't quite grasp how these translate to likelihood functions. For example, I am interested in Jones's (1992) double-hurdle model. In economics, this is a two-part model that can be useful for modeling excess zeros with a continuous dependent variable. For instance, someone can choose to buy something (first hurdle, called participation) and then, if they do, they can choose how much money to spend (second hurdle, called consumption).

I can follow the form of the model, which is:

If $X_2\beta_2 + v > 0$ and $X_1\beta_1 + u > 0$
then $y = y^* = X_2\beta_2 + v$

Otherwise $y = 0$

Where $y$ is the observed value of the dependent variable, $y^*$ is the unobserved latent value of the dependent variable, $X_1$ are the predictors for the first hurdle (participation), $\beta_1$ are the coefficients for the first hurdle (participation), $u$ is the residual for the first hurdle (participation), and $X_2$, $\beta_2$, and $v$ are the same elements, respectively, for the second hurdle (consumption).

$X_1$ and $X_2$ can contain all, some, or none of the same variables.

We also let $u$ and $v$ be related to one another, such that:

$(u, v) \sim \text{BVN}(0, \Sigma)$ where $\Sigma = \left[{\begin{array}{cc} 1 & \sigma\rho \\ \sigma\rho & \sigma^2 \\ \end{array}}\right]$

Now, all of the above makes sense to me, and I can explain it in words. We simultaneously predict if someone participates and their consumption. If both of these equations produce values larger than zero, then we observe the predicted value from the consumption equation. If not, then we observe a zero. We also let these two processes be related by letting their residuals be bivariate normally distributed (i.e., $\rho \neq 0$)

Where I run into issues is understanding how this translates into a likelihood function. Jones (1992) is pretty confident that this isn't too difficult to figure out. After some re-arranging and substituting of terms, Jones denotes the likelihood of this structure by:

$$L = \prod_0\{1 - \Phi(X_1\beta_1, X_2\beta_2/\sigma, \rho)\} \times \prod_+\{\Phi((X_1\beta_1 + {\rho \over \sigma}(y - X_2\beta_2))/\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}){1 \over \sigma}\phi((y - X_2\beta_2)/\sigma)\}$$

Where $\phi$ is the univariate normal $pdf$ and the $\Phi$ is the univariate normal $cdf$.

**Is there an intuitive explanation for how this likelihood function works and how it was constructed from the structural model?** I would like to be able to have a conceptual understanding of the likelihood function and how to use it. Even if someone just has a recommendation on something I should read to better understand how likelihood functions work, I would greatly appreciate that.

---

Jones, A. M. (1992). A note on the computation of the double-hurdle model with dependence with an application to tobacco expenditure. *Bulletin of Economic Research, 44*(1), 67 - 74. doi: 10.1111/j.1467-8586.1992.tb00507.x